# What is wrong with my code? Why won't it write the data I input into the the text file; anytime I open the actual text file, it's empty?

Tags: python

Also, why won't it write the data I input into the the text file, anytime I open the actual text file, It's empty.

```
global Newpass
global Network
global setpass
global password
Newpass=""
#i global these so i could use them again
def enteragain():

   if Newpass!=Newpass:
        Newpass=input("Enter again please,")

def newpass():
  Network=open("Userandpass.txt","r")
  lines=Network.readlines()
  passs=lines[1]
  sets=lines[2]
  print(passs)
  print(sets)
  Network.close()
  Network=open("Userandpass.txt","w")
  for i in range (3):
    if password==setpass:
      Newpass=input("Okay, choose a new password ")
      if len(Newpass)>= 8 and Newpass[0].isalnum()==True and Newpass[0].isupper()==True:
    enteragain()
    print("your username is", user," and your password is now",Newpass)

  else:
        print("password did not match requirements, try again ")
else:
     Newpass=input("Your password was wrong enter again please")
  print("3 tries up. Please try again later")

Network=open("Userandpass.txt","w")
Network.write=input("What is your Username")
Network.write=input("Set a password")
question=input("Do you want to change your password?")
if question=="yes":
  Network.write=input("What is your old password")
  newpass()
else:
  print("Okay thank you.")
Network.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sarah/OneDrive/Documents/python/challenge 1.py", line 40, 
in <module>
    newpass()
  File "C:/Users/sarah/OneDrive/Documents/python/challenge 1.py", line 15, 
in newpass
    passs=lines[1]
IndexError: list index out of range`
```

What does the syntax error actually mean? It is a password re-setter for school that I have no idea how to fix.

Comment: Your file probably contains less than two lines. However, many things look wrong in your code... like `if Newpass != Newpass:`: how could it be different from itself?

Comment: if they enter the password again and its not equal to the initial one they put in, then it would say enter again

Comment: You posted a Traceback for an IndexError.  Are you getting a syntax error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  When you [Caught the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspected/printed relevant data in the except suite, what did you find?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem which you are facing currently is because once you wrote data inside file you never closed it. Means when you again open it in read mode there won't be any committed data inside it. Sure the file is created but you need to close the connection to commit the data. Just take the look at updated code snippet I fixed it with few minor issues too so you can move ahead.

```
Newpass=""
Network=""
setpass=""
password=""
Newpass=""

def newpass():
    Network=open("Userandpass.txt")
    lines=Network.readlines()
    passs=lines[1]
    sets=lines[2]
    print(passs)
    print(sets)
    Network.close()
    Network=open("Userandpass.txt","a")
    for i in range (3):
        if password==setpass:
            newpass=input("Okay, choose a new password ")
            if len(newpass)>= 8 and newpass[0].isalnum()==True and newpass[0].isupper()==True:
                print("your username is : ", lines[0]," and your password is now", newpass)
                Network.write("New Password is : " + newpass)
                Network.close()
                break
            else:
                print("password did not match requirements, try again ")
    print("3 tries up or else password updated")

Network=open("Userandpass.txt","w")
Network.write(input("What is your Username") + "\n")
Network.write(input("Set a password") + "\n")
question=input("Do you want to change your password?")
if question=="yes":
    Network.close()
    newpass()
else:
     Network.close()
     print("Okay thank you.")
```

Let me know if you face any issue here while trying to make sense of it.